# How to set the hash_function of PHP native file session in Symfony 3

Tags: php, session, symfony

I want to set the hash_function of PHP Native file sessions, so that the session ID has more entropy in Symfony 3 framework, but the configuration options of session does not allow that. I managed to do it by changing the Dependency Injector options and allowed directives in the framework, but I want to do it by configuration, not by hard-coding it and losing it after update.

Do you have any alternatives for that, apart from extending and altering existing Symfony framework component? Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this may help:

```
ini_set( 'session.hash_function',  "sha256" );
```

You can read more about `ini_set` at [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: My idea is to do it through Symfony abstraction, not directly setting the ini-value.